# Mongo DB skip and limit

Tags: mongodb

I want 10,000 rows in a collection. I want to display 10 records first and when user clicks next, next set of 10 records and when user clicks next, next set of 10 records and goes on...

Example or Expected Result

```
// Page 1
db.students.find().limit(5)

// Page 2
db.students.find().skip(5).limit(5)

// Page 3
????
```

The page 3 specified in the web-site doesn't show a different query instead the same skip and limit is performed.

https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr

My question is do we need to execute the following query for page 3 ???

```
// Page 3
db.students.find().skip(10).limit(5)   (OR)
db.students.find().skip(5).limit(5) as specified in the link
```

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that you have to calculate `skips` based on the current page number and use `.skip(skips)`. This is shown in an example function `skiplimit()`. Please be sure to read through that tutorial more carefully as the answer to your question is contained within.

Comment: B. Fleming..I still don't understand. Can you please kindly explain in detail if any image if possible. that would be really appreciatable

Answer (score 0):

```
const limit = 10 // Numbers of items you want to display per page
const page = 1 // This value should change dynamically when user select other page
const skip = (page - 1) * limit // for skipping the items
```

This Example will show exactly 10 elements (if enough items are available in your database) of 1st page without skipping any elements (skip = 0).